# Taylor polynomial approximation with absolute error less than 3 decimal places

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

Assume that f is a function with $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le 11,$ for all n and all real x. Let $T_n(x)$ denote the Taylor polynomial of degree n for f(x) about the point $x=0$.

What is the least integer n for which you can be sure that $T_n(2)$ approximates f(2) accurately to 3 decimal places? i.e., so that the absolute error $\displaystyle \left|R_n\left(2\right)\right|$ is less than $\displaystyle \frac{5}{10^{4}} = 0.0005$ ? Here $\displaystyle R_n\left(2\right)$ denotes the Lagrange form of the Remainder, evaluated at $\displaystyle 2$.

---

So I'm guessing that for whatever derivative $n$, my function will always be less than 11.

So the remainder:

$$ \frac{f^{n+1} (c) \cdot x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} < 0.0005 $$ should be less than 3 decimal places

->

$$ \frac{11 \cdot 2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}  < \frac{5}{10^4} $$

->

$$ \frac{(n+1)!}{2^{n+1}} > 22000$$

but how do I solve for $n$ manually?

By trial and error n = 11.

Comment: In your computations you have set $x=2$ instead of $x=1/2$. What you need to solve is $2^{n+1}(n+1)!>22000$. This is much easier to do by trial and error.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre the value is for previous problem, which was easy to solve. I will edit the problem now.

Comment: Take log of both sides and use [$\log n!\approx n\log n-n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).